# How to loop to check if all values in a list are bigger than the values in another list?

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

As the question suggests, how do I do a loop to check if all values in a list are bigger than another set of values in another list? Assuming that the length of each list is the same and each value will be compared to another based on its index.

For example:

```
aList=[1,5,10,15,23]
bList=[0,4,9,14,22]
for x in range(len(aList)):
   if aList[x]>bList[x]:
      print("All values in aList are bigger than bList")
   else:
      print("Not all values in aList are bigger than bList")
```

This is what I have now, but due to the loop, I ended up printing 5 times. I only wish for the result to print once. Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat if you read carefully, I think he's looking for pairwise comparison for each element

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#all) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
if all(a > b for a, b in zip(aList, bList)):
    print("All values in aList are bigger than bList")
else:
    print("Not all values in aList are bigger than bList")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy:

```
import numpy 

if np.all(np.array(aList) > np.array(bList)):
    print("All values in aList are bigger than bList")
else:
    print("Not all values in aList are bigger than bList")
```

Comment: Using `numpy` for such a trivial task would be overkill in my opinion

Comment: For large array-like operations, numpy is the only answer :)

Comment: @Vishnudev I don't know in what way you think this would be overkill.  Numpy is easily available, well supported and far more performant than native python for array operations.

Comment: otoh... I would reach for your `zip` + `all`solution for a trivial (< 100) set of items, and scale up only as necessary.  Both valid solutions for sure.

Comment: I agree that for larger arrays and multiple manipulations `numpy` would be useful. Creating `numpy` arrays itself is a costly operation and hence if you are looking for trivial inputs like one OP provided, it should not be used.

Comment: Numpy isn't only overkill for this problem, it's also slower than the stdlib. I ran a timing experiment with @Vishnudev's stdlib solution and this solution. This solution consistently took twice as long on worst-case test cases up to size 10^9. The other advantage of @Vishnudev's solution is that it can take advantage of generators for large problem sizes while this solution will materialize any generator as a `np.array`, for really large cases this could cause the host machine to swap.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation:

```py
isGreater = True
for x in range(len(aList)):
    if aList[x]<bList[x]:
        isGreater = False
        break
if isGreater:
    print("List A is greater than List B")
else:
    print("List A is not greater than List B")
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the approach that you have done, simply set a flag variable, and after the loop check the flag and print the result. Below is the implementation

```py
aList=[1,5,10,15,23]
bList=[0,4,9,14,22]
for x in range(len(aList)):
   if aList[x] < bList[x]:
      flag = True
      break
if flag:
    print('bList is bigger')
else:
    print('aList is bigger')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
aList=[1,5,10,15,23]
bList=[0,4,9,14,22]
aisbigger=True
for x in aList:
   for y in bList:
      if(x<y):
         aisbigger=False
if(aisbigger):
   print("All values in aList are bigger than bList")
else:
   print("Not all values in aList are bigger than bList")
```

after edit:
if i am not wrong you want to compare every element only with same indexed element in the other list. then try this:

```
aList=[1,5,10,15,23]
bList=[0,4,9,14,22]
aisbigger=True
for x in range(len(aList)):
   if(aList[x]<bList[x]):
         aisbigger=False
if(aisbigger):
   print("All values in aList are bigger than bList")
else:
   print("Not all values in aList are bigger than bList")
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make a minor tweak to your code. Rather than printing at each element just check the condition and at the end print depending on the value of the boolean variable, eachGreater in this case

```
aList=[1,5,10,15,23]
bList=[0,4,9,14,22]

eachGreater = True

for x in range(len(aList)):
    if aList[x]>bList[x]:
        pass
    else:
        eachGreater = False
        break

if eachGreater:
    print("All values in aList are bigger than bList")
else:
    print("Not all values in aList are bigger than bList")
```

Answer (score 0):

`Numpy` approach using the module `greater_equal`

```
a=[1,5,10,15,23]
b=[0,4,9,14,22]

#Approach 1

if np.greater_equal(a,b).all():
    print("All values in aList are bigger than bList")
else:
    print("Not all values in aList are bigger than bList")
```

will give you

> All values in aList are bigger than bList

and

re-run the code for `a=[1,5,10,15,20]` will give you

> Not all values in aList are bigger than bList

Comment: But I still prefer Vishnudev suggestion as it has the advantage of short-circuit evaluation once the condition is true and it does not require import extra `library` such as `numpy` in my case

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the most straight forward solution. It’s a small adaptation from what you already have.

```py
def each_item_larger(a, b):
    for pos in range(len(a)):
        if (a[pos] < b[pos]):
            return False
    return True

aList = [1, 5, 10, 15, 23]
bList = [0, 4, 9, 14, 22]

if each_item_larger(aList, bList):
    print(“Each item is larger.”)
else:
    print(“At least one item is smaller.”)
```